# WhatsApp - can I name a voice message?

Tags: whatsapp

Is it possible to give a text name to a Whatsapp voice message before sending?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can name voice message

Comment: How do I do so?

Comment: Without any information on how to do so, this is a pretty immaterial answer.